# FQL not returning all friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

My FQL looks like this:

```
$fql = "select name,username,pic_small,uid,hometown_location,current_location from user where uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2=me())";
```

I think this query should return all my friends but when I compare friends count on my facebook profile with result I get from above query, it is different. What to do to get same count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can opt out of the Facebook app platform entirely.  You are accessing it properly, but some of your friends have strong privacy settings in place.  This can be set by going to Privacy Settings -> App And Websites -> Turn off all platform apps.

[image]

Comment: How to opt out from facebook app platform? I am not able to find it from setting :(